# Aquire Singleton class Instance Multithread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, synchronization, singleton, delphi-6

To get the instance of the class with Singleton pattern, I want use the following function:

**This is a sketch**

```
interface

uses SyncObjs;

type
  TMCriticalSection = class(TCriticalSection)
  private
    Dummy : array [0..95] of Byte;
  end;

var
  InstanceNumber : Integer;
  AObject: TObject;
  CriticalSection: TMCriticalSection;

function getInstance: TObject;

implementation

uses Windows;

function getInstance: TObject;
begin
   //I Want somehow use InterlockedCompareExchange instead of CriticalSession, for example

   if InterlockedCompareExchange(InstanceNumber, 1, 0) > 0 then
   begin
     Result := AObject;
   end
   else
   begin
      CriticalSection.Enter;
      try
        AObject := TObject.Create;
      finally
        CriticalSection.Leave;
      end;
      InterlockedIncrement(InstanceNumber);
      Result := AObject
   end;
end;

initialization
  CriticalSection := TMCriticalSection.Create;
  InstanceNumber := 0;

finalization;
  CriticalSection.Free;

end.
```

Three Questions:

1- Is this design Thread Safe? Especially the with InterlockedExchange Part. 
2- How to use the InterlockedCompareExchange? Is it possible to do what i'm trying? 
3- Is this design better than involve all code within the critical section scope?

**Remark:
My object is thread safe, only the construction i need to serialize! 

This is not the intire code, only the important part, i mean, the getInstance function.**

### Edit

I **NEED** to use some kind of singleton object. 
Is there any way to use InterlockedCompareExchange to compare if the value of InstanceNumber  is zero?  
And 
1 - Create the object only when is 0, otherwise, return the instance. 
2 - When the value is 0: Enter in the critical section. Create the object. Leave critical section. 
3 - Would be better to do this way, instead of involve all code within the critical section scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your design does not work and this can be seen even without any understanding of what `InterlockedCompareExchange` does. In fact, irrespective of the meaning of `InterlockedCompareExchange`, your code is broken.

To see this, consider two threads arriving at the `if` statement in `getInstance` at the same time. Let's consider the three options for which branches they take:

1. They both choose the second branch. Then you create two instances and your code no longer implements a singleton.
2. They both choose the first branch. Then you never create an instance.
3. One choose the first and the other chooses the second. But since there is no lock in the first branch, the thread that takes that route can read `AObject` before the other thread has written it.

Personally I'd use [double-checked locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805769/does-delphi-assign-the-variable-before-the-object-is-constructed#10812621) if I had to implement your `getInstance` function.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i get so excited about using InterlockedCompare, that i not even realise about this part. thank you

Comment: The best way to do this, is put all code inside the critical section context, is this right?

Comment: You can use double checked locking which does work in Delphi on x86/x64. I added a link in my answer to another answer here (one of mine) that covers this topic in more detail.

Comment: what about this http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: Read the answer that I linked to. Essentially the x86 and x64 memory models are strong, and Delphi doesn't optimise reads/writes from/to globals into registers. So, DCL works in Delphi on x86/x64

Comment: Double-checked will work to me. Despite my lack of proficiency in English, you could understand what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: Well, it took a while. Your English seems fine. I think a little more of an explanation in the question would have helped, but I think we got there in the end.

Comment: What i really don't understand is why people was decreasing my question before understanding what i was asking.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30130/discussion-between-david-heffernan-and-matheus-freitas)

Comment: Thank you David, and everybody others who at least read the post and tried to help!

Answer (score 5):

There is a technique called [*"Lock-free initialization"*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/07/10150728.aspx) that does what you want:

```pascal
interface

function getInstance: TObject;

implementation

var
   AObject: TObject;

function getInstance: TObject;
var
   newObject: TObject;
begin
   if (AObject = nil) then
   begin
      //The object doesn't exist yet. Create one.
      newObject := TObject.Create;

      //It's possible another thread also created one.
      //Only one of us will be able to set the AObject singleton variable
      if InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(AObject, newObject, nil) <> nil then
      begin
         //The other beat us. Destroy our newly created object and use theirs.
         newObject.Free;
      end;
   end;

   Result := AObject;
end;
```

The use of `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer` erects a full memory barrier around the operation. It is possible one might be able to get away with  `InterlockedCompareExchangeRelease` to use *release semantics* (to ensure the construction of the object completes before performing the compare exchange).  The problem with that is:

- i'm not smart enough to know if **Release** semantics alone really will work (just cause a smarter person than me said they would, doesn't mean i know what he's talking about)
- you're constructing an object, the memory barrier performance hit is the least of your worries (it's the thread safety)

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.

Comment: +1, it seems light-weight...Have you studied the possibility of reordering? Is this free of it? That's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You should add your answer here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392107/delphi-singleton-pattern?lq=1

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound It's memory safe because `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer` erects a *full* memory barrier. It is entirely [likely that i could get away with `InterlockedCompareExchangePointerRelease` semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/07/10150728.aspx), but i'm too much of a chicken.